# When typing letter 'c' is getting converted into letter 'o'

Tags: javascript, html, browser, encoding

For one particular client, our website is converting letter `c` into the letter `o`. Even in the text that is coming from backend all the `c`s are appearing as `o`. It is happening only for the letter `c`. Everything else is working just fine.

We tested it ourselves when our client shared his screen. When we open a new tab and go to any other website, it works just fine, as its suppose to.

We are using ruby on rails in the backend and frontend we're using usual javascript libraries like `jquery, fontawesome, jquery-ui` and framework `backbonejs` & `handlebars` as templating.

Encoding on response header is coming like this

`Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8`

Client is using `windows 7` with `chrome`

Comment: Wow, that's weird. It seems like a joke/rewrite rule on one proxy!

Comment: Is the HTML source returned have the c replaced with o?

Comment: From what I can understand, by seeing your question, the issue lies somewhere in backend code and not the frontend, the frontend application is just displaying what is coming from backend without any modifications. But without code, it is difficult to provide any suggestion. So it would be great if some sample code is shared. And also check the network tab with the request headers being passed, might be charset being sent is different

Comment: Or is it changed after the response is received?

Comment: share your website link

Comment: It cannot be a backend issue, because when you write 'c' in any text fields 'o' is being written. All the 'c's in the webpage are appearing as 'o's. And its happening only for that one client. Everywhere else its working just fine.

Comment: Have they tried IE or Firefox? Or, to rule out the browser, what if they download the webpage directly, with a tool like wget or curl or whatever. You _are_ sure that they're actual o's, right? Not just c's in a font that makes them look like o's.

Comment: The client tried different browsers as well from what he told. The issue seems to be there in all browsers. Please let me know if there is any other information you might need to diagnose, I'll arrange a TeamViewer session and gather whatever information I can.

Comment: have you checked character encoding in the html page